# After soundcloud authentication, safari not opening the app

Tags: iphone, safari, soundcloud

I have created an iPhone application. I have integrated with SoundCloudAPI.

To authorize it, automatically the application will launch the SoundCloud website in safari. After authentication, it is giving following error message;

"Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid".

It is not coming back to my current application.

Please guide me to resolve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it.

Issue is; I did not change the callback url.

Now it is working fine.